# How to sync mouse pointer correctly in screen sharing when connecting to a Windows VM?

Tags: windows, mouse, screen-sharing

I am using the screen sharing application on a MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.3 to connect to a Windows 7 virtual machine on a different computer.

Although the keyboard and mouse work in general (input is received by the VM), the mouse pointer is not synced correctly. I see two mouse pointers: the Windows one and the one from my Mac. However, the Windows mouse pointer is always off by quite a bit. It seems to have a higher acceleration. If I quickly move my mouse, the Windows mouse pointers moves more than my Mac's.

I cannot find any information on the Web about this problem. Is this a known issue? Should it work with Windows systems?

Comment: i think this has to do with the Network Delay and not with the Acceleration of the Mouse on the Windows PC. With the Big Brother of Screensharing Apples "Remote Desktop" you can say you want to fully take over the control that way the cursor on the Remotemachine disapers. If you don't want to spend 80$ for this, it may help you to use another VNC Server on the Windowsmachine or just try out "Microsoft Remote Desktop" for Mac which uses the RDP Protocol which is much more used/known than VNC in the Windows-World.

Comment: I have the same problem, I see 2 mouse pointers, the black one of my Mac (10.11.5) and the white one of my remote RHEL 6.

Answer (score 4):

In the Screen Sharing app, go to the View menu and click "Customize Toolbar..." There's a button you can add to the toolbar called "Cursor" that toggles your Mac's mouse cursor. You can turn it off so you'll only see the one on the remote machine instead of both the remote and local cursor.

Answer (score 0):

think this double pointer has something to do with your screen resolution but not the size of the screen. but where it says make text larger or smaller , reduce the percentage back to 100 maybe higer but at 200% of the normal size , the mouse becomes distorted and are inches apart.